# calling sed from ant, unknown command

Tags: sed, ant

I'm trying to exec sed from an ant build script (yes, this is a very old project, and it is a one-off).

Here is the build xml:

```
                 <exec executable="/opt/local/bin/sed">
                    <arg value="-i.bak"/>
                    <arg value="-e"/>
                    <arg value="&quot;s:\&amp;:\&amp;amp;:g&quot;"/>
                    <arg value="file"/>
            </exec>
```

Ant's verbose output follows:

```
 [exec] Executing '/opt/local/bin/sed' with arguments:
 [exec] '-i.bak'
 [exec] '-e'
 [exec] '"s:\&:\&amp;:g"'
 [exec] 'file'
 [exec]
 [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [exec] not part of the command.
 [exec] /opt/local/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

I've tried single quotes as well, that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you change it to [ant replace task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) ?

Comment: excellent question-- sed is my go-to tool for this, but I will try that out!

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as was pointed out in a comment, was to use the native ant replace task.